# Page Scroll issues in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In Angular js when the user clicks on a button that navigates him to a new page, the corresponding new page is starting from the bottom which makes the user to- scroll all the way back to the top...this can be sometimes quite hard.So I want the page to directly start from the top on the click of a button..?Any help appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

HTML code:

```
<div class="panel-body form-horizontal">
          <button type="button" ng-click="activeStep=1" class="btn btn-default pull-right" ><i
            class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" ng-click=" scrollonclick('editCid')" ></i> Edit
         </button>
```

controller code:

```
$scope.scrollonclick = function(selection){
  switch(selection){
    case 'editCid':
      $location.hash('editCid');
      $anchorScroll();
      break;
```

Comment: <div class="panel-body form-horizontal">
              <button type="button" ng-click="activeStep=1" class="btn btn-default pull-right" ><i
                class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" ng-click=" scrollonclick('editCid')" ></i> Edit
             </button>

Comment: please add it to the question.

Comment: controller code:
$scope.scrollonclick = function(selection){
      switch(selection){
        case 'editCid':
          $location.hash('editCid');
            $anchorScroll();
              break;

Comment: I edited your post to format the code : you have to let one blank space and start your line by 4 spaces to show code blocks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, of all we should use an id to refer to an element.Then we should use the ng-click='functionname' to make the element get clicked by the mouse click.Then w should use the following code in the controller part:
          Use this controller code in the controller part we can make the control come to that particular element.
     controller code:    $scope.gotoScroll = function (section) {
    switch (section) {
      case 'editClaimAssertion':
        $scope.showNextStep(1);
        $location.hash('editClaimAssertion');
        break;

Answer (score 0):

Where is your element with id 'editCid'? Is it at the top of the page? If not, it will not scroll to the top.

There is also no need for the case.

```
   $scope.scrollonclick = function(selection){
          $location.hash(selection);
          $anchorScroll();
    };
```

You should consider posting your entire html template, assuming its not to big and your entire controller as well.

Comment: Actually I used the id to just reflect the particular element. And next edit Cid is the id which is used to associate the first page .